# Foundation 5 Compatibility version Browser : Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari

Tags: version, zurb-foundation, compatibility

Which version supports the Foundation 5 browser: Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari? For 
both Desktop and Mobile?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Foundation 5 support all popular browsers versions(Exceprt IE8 and IE7)